# Permissions on Global Secondary Index

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I am using `sam` to define a `dynamodb` table as such:

```
#DynamoTables
  DevicesTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: devices
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - 
          AttributeName: "id"
          AttributeType: "S"
        - 
          AttributeName: "customerId"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema:
        - 
          AttributeName: "id"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        -
          AttributeName: "customerId"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes: 
        - 
          IndexName: "customers"
          KeySchema: 
            - 
              AttributeName: "customerId"
              KeyType: "HASH"
          Projection: 
            ProjectionType: "ALL"   
          ProvisionedThroughput: 
            ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
            WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
```

I am able to access the table using a lambda function with `Properties: Policies: AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` defined in sam and defining the put params using the `TableName: 'devices'` in `node`. However, when I attempt to query the index by defining the query on an index as such:

```
params = {
  TableName: 'devices',
  IndexName: 'customers'
  // ...
}
```

I get an error stating the lambda function does not have permissions to access that index:

> AccessDeniedException: User: User: arn:aws:sts:::assumed-role/CodeStarWorker-Lambda/awscodestar-lambda-DeviceFunction is not authorized to
>   perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: TABLEURL/devices/index/customers

Anyone know a way I can grant this access or work around this to query the index?

UPDATE:
I don't think the AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess policy is affecting things, when I removed it from the `template.yml` i was still able to put to the table and still unable to query on the index. Do I have to manually add roles?

Comment: So I was able to fix it by manually adding dynamodb full access to the iam role for the lambda worker, but its supposed to be done through the template.yml so kind of a pain

Answer (score 15):

Your lambda has access to TABLEURL/devices but not to TABLEURL/devices/index/customers.

Here is an examplefrom aws docs on how to do allow access to all indexes of a db.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AccessAllIndexesOnBooks",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/Books",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/Books/index/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you know the specific action that's needed for this?